# Julia: ODBC.jl unable to connect properly to my sqlite database and retrieve data

Tags: database, sqlite, odbc, julia

I am unable to connect to my simple database using sqlite and odbc.jl. I am using MacOS Sierra, Version 10.12.3
Short summary: Manages to connect, it retrieves the correct column names, but is unable to retrieve any of the data.

Long set of steps:

Showing the sqlite database:

```
using SQLite
db_path = "~/test_db.db"
test_db = SQLite.DB(db_path)
println(SQLite.query(test_db, "SELECT * FROM test"))
```

Results in:

```
4×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ id │ name    │
├─────┼────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1  │ "name1" │
│ 2   │ 2  │ "name2" │
│ 3   │ 3  │ "name3" │
│ 4   │ 4  │ "name4" │
```

Installing the ODBC sqlite driver:

```
brew install sqlite
```

Which now gives:

```
Warning: sqliteodbc-0.9995 already installed
```

Then I followed the documentation at
http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/html/index.html
and
http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html
and created a template and updated ini file.

/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[SQLite]
Description=SQLite driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Threading=2
```

/usr/local/etc/template:

```
[SQLite]
Description     = SQLite driver
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Setup           = /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Threading       = 2
```

And ran:

```
odbcinst -i -d -f template
```

Which output:

```
odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 3. 
Target directory is /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc
```

Now back to julia, running:

```
using ODBC
ODBC.listdrivers()
```

Gives:

```
String["SQLite" "Description=SQLite driver\0Driver=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so\0Setup=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so\0Threading=2\0UsageCount=3\0"]
```

Then I try to create a dsn:

```
dsn = ODBC.DSN("Driver=SQLite;Database=/Users/nick_thiessen/test_db.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;")
println(dsn)
ODBC.query( dsn, "SELECT * FROM test")
```

Which gives:

```
ODBC.DSN(DSN=;Database=/Users/nick_thiessen/test_db.db;StepAPI=0;Timeout=1000;SyncPragma=NORMAL;NoTXN=0;ShortNames=;LongNames=0;NoCreat=;NoWCHAR=;FKSupport=;Tracefile=;JournalMode=;LoadExt=;BigInt=;JDConv=;PWD=)
0×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
  id name
```

Somehow it's able to discern the column names of the test table, but not find the data

Comment: A good soul already reproduced this error and opened an issue in the ODBC.jl package. Here is the link: https://github.com/JuliaDB/ODBC.jl/issues/157